# Boolean expression must not be null?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter

Does anyone know why i got the Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null.
If I had logged in and quit the app and open the app again i should be directly in the homescreen.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  bool userIsLoggedIn = false;

  @override
  void initState(){
    getLoggedInState();
    super.initState();
  }

  getLoggedInState()async{
    await HelperFunction.getUserLoggedInSharedPreference().then((value){
      setState(() {
        userIsLoggedIn = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: userIsLoggedIn ? HomeScreen() : CompanyLoadingBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the call stack. What if the logged in preference is not yet set?

Comment: @ThienLD Could you post a answer where you show it with code?

Answer (score 2):

If your 'value' here can become null - you get the error.
To be safe change the line inside setState to:

```
userIsLoggedIn = value ?? false;
```

it will set the bool to false if value is null

Comment: If I do this the error is gone but when I had logged in and run the app again it shows me the Sign In screen again

Comment: It works because the value is null, this means that the problem is in how HelperFunction.getUserLoggedInSharedPreference() handles stuff inside of it - why does it return null in the first place? Nothing to do with understanding what a Future is, duh.

Comment: This is my HelperFunction part :            
````static Future<bool> getUserLoggedInSharedPreference()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                           return prefs.getBool (sharedPreferenceUserLoggedInKey);
  }````

Comment: Sorry about the late answer, I think the best solution here would be if check out the usage example on shared_preferences page and try to follow it in your code: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example

Answer (score 0):

Your issue most likely lies in this function where you're setting `userIsLoggedIn` to null. Ensure `getUserLoggedInSharedPreference` actually returns a boolean and not null.

```dart
  void getLoggedInState() async {
    final result = await HelperFunction.getUserLoggedInSharedPreference();
    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        userIsLoggedIn = result;
      });
    } else {
      print("result is null");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have changed it but when I restart my app it shows me the sign in screen again and not the homescreen.

Comment: Must be an issue with your shared preferences then.

Comment: This is my HelperFunction part :                                                       ````static Future<bool> getUserLoggedInSharedPreference()async{                      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();                            return prefs.getBool (sharedPreferenceUserLoggedInKey);   }````

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not waiting for your Future to resolve to an actual value.

This line:

```
userIsLoggedIn = value;
```

might not have been reached when your build method is called. Because it's `async` and you don't `await` it.

You can set a default value to `userIsLoggedIn`, maybe `false`, that will solve your immediate problem. But it will not solve your real problem, that your program logic is asynchronous.

You will probably want to build your app with at least one `FutureBuilder`.

See: [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Follow the link, read and understand it, then implement it for your code. If you have *specific* problems doing that, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have a global approach error. You combine `traditional` and `async/await` methods in this code:

```dart
getLoggedInState()async{
    await HelperFunction.getUserLoggedInSharedPreference().then((value){
      setState(() {
        userIsLoggedIn = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

If you use `async/await` you should not use `then` method.

To implement what you want you should use something like this:

```dart
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: HelperFunction.getUserLoggedInSharedPreference(),
      builder: (context,snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // Future is ready. Take data from snapshot
          userIsLoggedIn = snapshot.data; // bool value is here
          return userIsLoggedIn ? HomeScreen() : CompanyLoadingBar();
        } else {
          // Show progress while future will be completed
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
    ),
  );
}
...
```

And also check what value is returned from `HelperFunction.getUserLoggedInSharedPreference()`. It seems it returns `null` because I think you have no already saved value. So you need to specify the default value:

```dart
final value = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().readBool(name) ?? false;
```